# update richtextbox from vb class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am running a function through a class and I want to output the results to a **RichTextBox** on my **MainForm**.

```
memSearch.execute(inpMemRows, outMemRows, Mpi.[GetType].ASENTITY, Mpi.SearchType.ASMEMBER)

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim iter As Mpi.RowIterator = outMemRows.rows()

While iter.hasMoreRows()
    Dim row As Mpi.MemRow = DirectCast(iter.nextRow(), Mpi.MemRow)
    MainForm.RichTextBox1.Text = row.getString("memhead")
End While
```

how can I accomplish this?

Currently, I am using **MessageBox** and obviously I don't want that. So I know the code is working where I need the data.

> But how do I get the data to the **RichTextBox**?

Comment: You either pass a reference of the RTB to the class (not recommended) or your form has a reference to the class, and the class returns the RTF information that the RTB can use.  Either way, someone needs to knock on the other's door and ask, "Can I have that?"

Comment: How can I do that? I have found examples online but none of them make sense to me. I am still learning VB.

Comment: I can't see your code from here.  Your main form should have a reference to an instance of that class, so that it can call the function that returns the information, which it can then use to populate the RTB.  Your example code looks like a lot of global variables, which will lead you to spaghettiville.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to put all the rows in the `RichTextBox` then change this line:

```
MainForm.RichTextBox1.Text = row.getString("memhead")
```

To be:

```
MainForm.RichTextBox1.Text &= row.getString("memhead") & vbCrLf
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
MainForm.RichTextBox1.Text = MainForm.RichTextBox1.Text & row.getString("memhead") & vbNewLine
```